# Import multiple GML files into PostgreSQL 11

Tags: postgis, postgresql, import, gml

I have some 50 GML files in my downloads folder, each within a child folder such as:

```
Downloads\Adur\Land_Registry_Cadastral_Parcels.gml
Downloads\Abertawe_-_Swansea\Land_Registry_Cadastral_Parcels.gml
Downloads\Allendale\Land_Registry_Cadastral_Parcels.gml
etc...
```

I want to import all 50 GML files into a public schema as a **batch command**. I want to name each table as per the child folder (Adur, Abertawe_-_Swansea, Allendale etc) rather than the GML file itself. The DB has the PostGIS extension enabled. I'm using **pgAdmin 4** as my visual SQL DB and expecting an idiot's guide on how to do this.

Comment: If using QGIS this can be done in the DB Manager with PostGIS connection

Comment: I see I can open the SQL query window there too but I wouldn't know what to type!

Comment: Install QGIS. Then you have multiple import options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading via **DBManager** in QGIS

use the **Import Layer/File**

[image]

Importing takes about 50 seconds.

[image]

This method allows for multiple files to be selected. (Or just merge all .gml files in QGIS)

Comment: Thanks Mapperz, this is the last resort I would have defaulted to myself - as you found and downloaded the inspire dataset for one local authority, you'll appreciate that merging all freehold titles for the UK will take some time!